# JavaScript promises behaviour: calling global function vs local function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am learning about promises in JavaScript and encounter some weird thing

```js
const successFunc = msg => {
    console.log(`Success ${msg}`);
};

const failFunc = msg => {
    console.log(`Fail ${msg}`);
};

// create a promise object
// inside the promise object, there is a logic gate inside.
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const a = 5;
    const b = 1;
    if (a > b) {
        // it will call the resolve function
        resolve();
    } else {
        // it will call the reject function
        reject();
    }
});

// // the promise object is activate and start when calling
// // this is actually an object chain promise.then(func).catch(func)
promise
    .then(successFunc("calling successFun"))
    .catch(failFunc("calling Fail Func"));

promise
    .then(() => {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("fail");
    });
```

In the first version, I expect this to return only the message from `successFunc` but somehow, it will return both of them. 
In the second version, the function is created inside instead globally, this somehow creates the behaviour I expect, which is calling success message only. Could someone provide more information about this behaviour?

This is the output:

```
>> node .\promise.js
Success calling successFun
Fail calling Fail Func
success
```

Comment: You're calling the functions and passing the *results* to then and catch; for this to work they need to be higher-order functions, functions that return functions, like `const createSuccessCallback = (msg) => () => console.log(msg);`. Your two examples **are not** equivalent, hence different results.

Comment: accept/upvote if the answer helped, check [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a value instead of a function as a callback to `.then` and `.catch`.
Provide a function and it should work.

```js
const successFunc = msg => {
    console.log(`Success ${msg}`);
};

const failFunc = msg => {
    console.log(`Fail ${msg}`);
};

// create a promise object
// inside the promise object, there is a logic gate inside.
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const a = 5;
    const b = 1;
    if (a > b) {
        // it will call the resolve function
        resolve();
    } else {
        // it will call the reject function
        reject();
    }
});

// // the promise object is activate and start when calling
// // this is actually an object chain promise.then(func).catch(func)
promise
    .then(() => successFunc("calling successFun"))
    .catch((e) => failFunc("calling Fail Func"));

promise
    .then(() => {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("fail");
    });
```

When you use it like

```
.then(successFunc("calling successFun"))
.catch(failFunc("calling Fail Func"));
```

then `successFunc("calling successFun")` are treated as function call, and are excuted and result is passed on to `.then`